# Nested Transaction using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

In my app, there are multiple steps where many commits to the database will be made sequentially through multiple methods.
Example:

```
A -> B -> C
       -> D
           ->E
       -> F
  -> G
```

A calls B which calls C. Then B calls D. D calls E and so on. All of these methods have some database operations.
As I understand from `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` (declarative transaction management - the spring recommended way), if **E** completes successfully, the transaction (and operations in **E** will be committed). Now, due to some exception, **F** should lead to a rollback. I want to have **everything**  rolled-back starting from what **A** did.
Is this possible via Declarative Transaction management? Or should I use Programmatic Transaction Management?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, "nested" transactions, in the sense that there are multiple running transactions depending on each other, is not supported, afaik.

Then, `propagation=REQUIRED` means that all methods with that propagation will:

- start a new transaction if there is none exists
- participate in an existing transaction if such exists.

This means that in your scenario, a failure in `F` would rollback the entire transaction (because it is a single transaction, started by `A`, and propagated to other methods)

Comment: I would have completely agreed with you until I read (somewhere - am unable to find where it was) that commit happens as soon as the method completes. I think I am wrong in the understanding here. When does the actual commit happen (we don't have to do explicitly do that. right?)?

Comment: the commit happens when the method that started the transaction completes. It is `A` in this case